# Leafletjs dynamically bound map to visible overlays

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leafletjs in my Rails app, adding the markers and using layer groups and overlays as "categories". I looked for examples and ideas on how I could bound/auto-zoom in and out based on the visible ("checked") overlays but couldn't find much.

Currently, I'm using a markers array that stores all the map markers and using the markers array to bound the map:

```
var group = L.featureGroup(markers); 
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

But I'm not sure how to dynamically update the bounds based on the visible overlay markers on the map. This is what I have so far:

```
var markers = [];

// a sample of the map markers
var consulting = new L.LayerGroup();
  <% @maps.each do |consulting| %> 
    <% if consulting.category == "Consulting" %>

    markers.push( L.marker( [<%= raw consulting.latitude.to_json %>, <%= raw consulting.longitude.to_json %>]));

    L.marker( [<%= raw consulting.latitude.to_json %>, <%= raw consulting.longitude.to_json %>],  {icon: consultingIcon} )
        .bindPopup( 'hello')
        .addTo(consulting);
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 


var education = new L.LayerGroup();
  <% @maps.each do |education| %> 
    <% if education.category == "Education" %>

      markers.push( L.marker( [<%= raw education.latitude.to_json %>, <%= raw education.longitude.to_json %>]));

      L.marker( [<%= raw education.latitude.to_json %>, <%= raw education.longitude.to_json %>],  {icon: educationIcon} )
        .bindPopup( 'hello')
        .addTo(education);
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 

var mbAttr = '' +
  'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidGVyZXNhc2hpaCIsImEiOiJjajU4cWFqNWgwMWgwMnFtazIycTJpbG51In0.4FH-NfH6b44wCc4BFodqWQ';

var grayscale   = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.light', attribution: mbAttr}),
  streets  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.streets',   attribution: mbAttr});

var map = L.map('mapid', {
  center: [43.6532, -79.3832],
  zoom: 5,
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  layers: [grayscale, consulting, education]
});

var baseLayers = {
  "Grayscale": grayscale,
  "Streets": streets
};

var overlays = {
  "Consulting": consulting,
  "Education": education
};

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);

var group = L.featureGroup(markers); 
map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can keep track of layers being added to and removed from the map using the `layeradd` and `layerremove` events. You'll need to build the bounds everytime one of your featuregroups gets added or removed. Working snippet with comments to elaborate:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ]
});

map.on('layeradd layerremove', function () {
    // Create new empty bounds
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds();
    // Iterate the map's layers
    map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        // Check if layer is a featuregroup
        if (layer instanceof L.FeatureGroup) {
            // Extend bounds with group's bounds
            bounds.extend(layer.getBounds());
        }
    });
    // Check if bounds are valid (could be empty)
    if (bounds.isValid()) {
        // Valid, fit bounds
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    } else {
        // Invalid, fit world
        map.fitWorld();
    }
});

var markers = new L.FeatureGroup([
    new L.Marker([-30, -30]),
    new L.Marker([30, -30]),
    new L.Marker([-30, -60]),
    new L.Marker([30, -60])
]).addTo(map);

var polylines = new L.FeatureGroup([
    new L.Polyline([[-30, 30], [30, 60]]),
    new L.Polyline([[30, 30], [-30, 60]])
]).addTo(map);

var control = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
    'Markers': markers,
    'Polylines': polylines
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Using your example, I can add the `FeatureGroups` (as categories that I had) and selecting them does dynamically zoom the map to the visible markers but they are not displayed by default which I had before. 

Is there a way I could display all of the markers by default but only re-build the bounds everytime one of the `FeatureGroups` gets added or removed? I was able to add marker info window back but when I tried to `addTo(map)` for all of the `FeatureGroups` layers it just breaks the map. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, that's possible. If you attach the handler to the map before you add your layers. I've edited my example.

Comment: Thank you so much, after a few tweaks, it works perfectly. I added a padding to bounds `map.fitBounds(bounds, {padding: [15, 15]})` since my marker icons were getting cut off. I didn't know how to add the `bindPopup(where text in here came from the "@maps.each" loop)` so I ended up with storing the markers to an array (with the icon and bindPopup message) and then calling `var consultingMarkers = new L.FeatureGroup(cMarkers).addTo(map);`.

Comment: Is there a way to add `MarkerCluster`? I tried `var consultingMarkers = new L.markerClusterGroup(cMarkers).addTo(map);` and updated to `layer instanceof L.markerClusterGroup` but it breaks the map.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have some overlays (`consulting` and `education` Layer Groups) in a Layers Control, and you would like your map to automatically fit bounds of the visible markers whenever the user toggles one of these overlays.

Then the difficulty is that you need to retrieve the list of visible markers, so that you can compute their bounds and have the map adjust accordingly.

An easy solution would be to use [Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) plugin, an intermediate "parent" Feature Group that will get the markers, and to replace your category Layer Groups by SubGroups from that plugin. This way, when added to the map, those SubGroups will actually add their child markers into the parent group. It then becomes trivial to get the bounds of all visible markers:

```js
var parentGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map),
    subGroup1 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup),
    subGroup2 = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup);

// Add your markers into the appropriate SubGroup…

var overlays = {
  'SubGroup 1': subGroup1,
  'SubGroup 2': subGroup2
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays).addTo(map);

// Have the map adjust view anytime the user uses the Layers Control overlays.
map.on('overlayadd overlayremove', function () {
  var bounds = parentGroup.getBounds();

  // Fit bounds only if the Parent Group actually has some markers,
  // i.e. it returns valid bounds.
  if (bounds.isValid()) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/354/

Note that you no longer need your overall `markers` array to duplicate your markers into.

> Disclaimer: I am the author of that plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been looking for a way to add `leaflet.markercluster.js`. But, I'm still having trouble getting the bounds of all visible markers. I have the loop for all consulting markers to `addTo(subGroup1);`, and all education markers to `addTo(subGroup2);`. I changed `var parentGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map),` to `var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map),` but it just breaks the map.

Comment: You should probably make it a new question

Comment: I made a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45358983/leafletjs-dynamically-bound-to-visible-markers-clusters. Where I am using the plugins, the code I have so far and the problems I'm having. I'm also not sure if I am understanding the `SouthWest` and `NorthEast` parts correctly.

Comment: As for the `SouthWest` and `NorthEast` thing, it is just a check to avoid trying to fit the map to bounds of null area. This can be replaced by a slightly different check [isValid()](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#latlngbounds-isvalid) as proposed by iH8 in his answer. Let me update the above answer for clarity then.