# Leafletjs dynamically bound to visible markers/clusters

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This is related to a previous question: [Leafletjs dynamically bound map to visible overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286918/leafletjs-dynamically-bound-map-to-visible-overlays).

I am now using the `Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup` plugin with the `Leaflet.markercluster` plugin. Trying to set map bound to all visible markers and marker clusters. I am using 3 co-ordinates to test:

```
[43.6425657, -79.38705569999999]
[43.7164673, -79.3395846]
[-41.3142772, 174.8135975]
```

This is the code so far:

```
var map = L.map("mapid");
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(map);

map.setView([43.6532, -79.3832], 2);

var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map),
    consultingMarkers = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup).addTo(map),
    otherMarkers = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup).addTo(map);

// subGroup1
L.marker([43.6425657, -79.38705569999999]).addTo(consultingMarkers);
L.marker([43.7164673, -79.3395846]).addTo(consultingMarkers);

// subGroup2 
L.marker([-41.3142772, 174.8135975], {icon: otherIcon}).addTo(otherMarkers);

var overlays = {
  'consulting': consultingMarkers,
  'other': otherMarkers
};

L.control.layers(null, overlays, {
  collapsed: false
}).addTo(map);

map.on('overlayadd overlayremove', function () {
  var bounds = parentGroup.getBounds(),
      southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();

  // Fit bounds only if the Parent Group actually has some markers,
  // i.e. it returns valid bounds.
  if (southWest && !southWest.equals(bounds.getNorthEast())) {
    map.fitBounds(parentGroup.getBounds());
  }
});
```

So far, I am running into these problems:

1. Map does not bound to the [-41.3142772, 174.8135975] co-ordinate
2. Un-checking the "consulting" layer does not bound the map to the markers from the "other" layer which has the co-ordinate [-41.3142772, 174.8135975].

**Update**: it seems to have this bounding problem for single markers. I tried adding another marker co-ordinate [43.76089289999999, -79.4103427] which would be in the cluster. But if I remove "consulting" cluster and remove "other" layer. The map still does not bound to the last marker left on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are puzzled because when one of your SubGroups has only 1 marker, the `map.fitBounds` does not look to be executed?

In that case, that is simply the expected behaviour of the `!southWest.equals(bounds.getNorthEast())` check: it avoids executing the next block when `bounds` represents a null area, i.e. there is 0 or 1 marker into it.

By replacing the check by [`bounds.isValid()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#latlngbounds-isvalid), you avoid only the case when there is 0 marker, but in the case there is exactly 1 marker, it will allow executing the next block, therefore trying to fit bounds on a null area. In such case, Leaflet pans to that single marker and zooms to `maxZoom`.

```js
map.on('overlayadd overlayremove', function () {
  var bounds = parentGroup.getBounds();

  if (bounds.isValid()) {
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/355/

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the `SouthWest` and `NorthEast` check. By replacing the check with `bounds.isValid()`, now it works when updating the map. I also added a `map.fitBounds(parentGroup.getBounds());` for when the map loads, so it will bound to the visible markers.